# SPFx how to identify type of list's view?

Tags: listview, spfx

I am working in a code that fetch the custom views created in a list. 
The code looks like this:

```
public async getView(): Promise<IViews[]> {
let viewsList: IViews[] = [];

const itemsViews = await sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Avtal Demo").views.get();

itemsViews.forEach(item => {
  viewsList.push({
    Title: item.Title,
    Id: item.Id
  });
});
console.log(itemsViews);
return new Promise<IViews[]>(async resolve => {
  resolve(viewsList);
}); }
```

The console log print out all information about the view.

What I need to do is find the way to differentiate  a view that is a grouped view from one that is filtered view.

Is that possible?

Best regards
Americo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `ViewQuery` property of the `View` object to retrieve the full query.

If the view is grouped by anything, there will be a `<GroupBy ...` part in there.

You can check if the query contains this. If not, the view is not grouped.